# PCP confirmation email doen't contain user-login details. [ Drupal ]

Tags: drupal, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

After creating a PCP page this email (message template) is sent to user who has contributed and created a PCP page.

> Dear supporter,
>
> Thanks for creating a personal campaign page in support of **[Contribution page name]**. Promoting Your Page
>
> You can begin your fundraising efforts using our "Tell a Friend" form:
>
> ```
> Login to your account
> Click this link and follow the prompts
> ```
>
> Managing Your Page
>
> Whenever you want to preview, update or promote your page:
>
> ```
> Login to your account
> Go to your page
> ```
>
> When you view your campaign page WHILE LOGGED IN, the page includes
>   links to edit your page, tell friends, and update your contact info.
>
> Questions? Send email to: info@example.org

My question here is,

How user can login to site since I see that there is no new user created on the site. I am not sure how this works for other but without any user creation they won't be able to login to site or edit their PCP page.

Please correct me if I am missing something here, I think user should be created and one-time-login url should be sent to user on the same email (message template).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Site had a configuration **Who can register accounts?** as `administration only` because of which I was not getting the screen where the user will be created before you fill PCP informations. After I changed the settings everything seems to be working fine.

Configuration page link: `example.org/admin/config/people/accounts`

[image]